# Error CS0433 Duplicate GuidAttribute after upgrade to dot net core 6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, upgrade, visual-studio-2022

I just downloaded VS2022 this week and I am experimenting with upgrading some old projects from .Net 4 to .Net (Core) 6 using the MS Dot Net Upgrade Assistant.  The current project I am working on is a simple command line utility, and I have got the dreaded CS0433 error relating to a duplicate GuidAttribute:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0433  The type 'GuidAttribute' exists in both 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.PInvoke, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Runtime.InteropServices, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' POEUsage    C:\Users\Slave19\source\repos\MEUtilities\POEUsage\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs   12  Active
```

This error causes the build to fail.

The closest I've seen to my question is [GuidAttribute error in AssemblyInfo.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38227307/31326) from 7 years ago.  But that refers to updating AWS related stuff, that I don't have.

However, I do use several of NuGet packages listed as dependencies:

- CommandLineParser (2.7.82)
- CsvHelper (2.15.0)
- System.Data.DataSetExtensions (4.5.0)

(I know that the first two are way out of date.  I'm trying to stabilize the conversion to .Net Core before tackling that.)

In AssemblyInfo.cs I can comment out the GUID like this

```
// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
//[assembly: Guid("de69e404-a84b-4df5-9dd3-efbfd508d8f8")]
```

And that stops Error CS0433,  but then triggers Warning CA1016

```
warning CA1016: Mark assemblies with assembly version
```

So what is going on? How do I find where this conflict is occurring?  And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around a bit more, and trying to solve CA1016 for a library that wasn't generating Error CS0433, I'm going with this as a solution:

1. Comment out the GUID in AssemblyInfo.cs

```
// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
//[assembly: Guid("de69e404-a84b-4df5-9dd3-efbfd508d8f8")]
```

This allows the build to complete, but then triggers Warning CA1016.

2. To fix Warning CA1016, check the "Generate assembly info" checkbox in the project's properties:

[image]

Now all my warnings and errors have gone away!